# How would I construct a MySQL trigger which updates based on information in other tables?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table called `booking` which has an `start_date`, `expiry_date` and `course_id` field, and another table called `course` which stores the `duration` in months.

What I want to do is whenever a booking is made, to automatically set the expiry field based on the the course that was selected. So if `course_id` 5 was selected, and it has a duration of 12 months, then when the booking is inserted or updated it will get the `duration`, add that to the `start_date` and then update `expiry_date` accordingly.

Any thoughts? I know MySQL triggers will do this, but I really have no idea where to begin constructing them and what I can actually do with them.

Comment: imo, instead of trying to write triggers immediately. 1) Write and debug the logic to do all this as separate scripts in the first instance. 2) Then `refactor` into functions, procedures, views etc. 3) Then decide if you can put the logic in triggers? Why? 1) You know all the logic works! So if when you are doing step 2) it must be a 'transcription error' not a logic error. Step 3) You fully understand the process and will see what doesn't work in triggers. Please do not skip any or the three steps. This is how I do it ;-/

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have access to it, you would have to trigger a custom function inside the function that writes the initial booking information to the database.

Or you can edit the existing function to add the expiry date while the booking is being added.

EDIT: I just noticed you want to use MySql Triggers use:

```
AFTER INSERT
```

http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_insert.php